# Installing a script file in 1200 Linux servers

Tags: linux, ssh

I need put a script file and a line in crontab in 1200 Linux servers.
How could I do this task automatically ?

Comment: How do you access these servers?

Answer (score 1):

Many many options!

- write a script that connects via SSH to each of those servers, and have it create your script file & modify crontab!
- use Ansible!
- use SaltStack!
- use < some other configuration management framework >!

Seriously though, are you suggesting you are in charge of 1200 servers and the usual procedure of doing, well, *anything* is by hand? Flabbergasting!

Comment: To the downvoter: would you please care to elaborate why you thought this answer was not useful?

Comment: (I was one of the ups) I think the reason was that this question should be on the Unix SE, it should be much more specific and thus also the answer could be much more specific. For example, I would somehow install an ssh authorized key on all the servers and then I would execute commands with a script. But it is only one of the million possible solutions.

Comment: This question will be closed as unclear, the goal of the down was to be it also deleted (closed, downvoted questions without upvoted answers are automatically deleted in 9 or 30 days). And I think, this should happen, if the OP doesn't come back and elaborate his question. If he elaborates, then the question should be moved to the Unix SE. If he doesn't, the whole post should be deleted and sown with salt. The SE system is incapable to do this correctly (for example, the migration of this post is nearly unimaginable), so beside my close vote, I voted up the question and also your answer.

Comment: This was the best thing I've read all day because I learned where all these odd questions end up. Answer: Odd Question Heaven. Sweet! Edit: Or Hell, depends on who you are.